# Can I Autowire an Adapter Class?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, singleton, autowired

I have a singleton class that I created that is used as an adapter to our Influx database. It basically looks like:

```
public class InfluxDBAdapter {
    // some private static final query Strings       

    private static InfluxDBAdapter adapter = null;
    private static InfluxDB influxDB;

    private InfluxDBAdapter() {}

    public static InfluxDBAdapter getInstance() {
        if (adapter == null) {
            adapter = new InfluxDBAdapter();
            influxDB = InfluxDBFactory.connect(URL, USERNAME, PWD);
            influxDB.query(new Query(CREATE_DB, DB_NAME));
            influxDB.setLogLevel(InfluxDB.LogLevel.BASIC);
            influxDB.setDatabase(DB_NAME);
        }
        return adapter;
    }

    // some more methods to utilize the database
}
```

and then in another class, I use it like so:

```
@Service
public class SomeService {
    private InfluxDBAdapter adapter;

    public SomeService() {}

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        adapter = InfluxDBAdapter.getInstance();
    }
}
```

And so this works, but I'm in the midst of refactoring my code and I wanted to know if was possible to simply autowire my InfluxDBAdapter class vs what I'm currently doing and still achieve the same result?

Comment: Why not simply ditch the singleton and let Spring handle that instead.

Comment: Do you mean what was suggested in the answer? i.e. annotate w/ @Component and move the getInstance logic into a public constructor?

Comment: No... Don't annotate, just create an `@Configuration` annotated class that constructs the `InfluxDB` and the `InfluxDBAdapter` that way you can even use Spring Boot properties etc. to get the hardcoded properties you now use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an `@Configuration` class which both constructs the `InfluxDB` as well as your adapter. With this you could even make use of the Spring Boot properties support.

```
@Configuration
public class InfluxDBConfiguration {

  @Bean
  public InfluxDB influxDB() {
    InfluxDB influxDB = InfluxDBFactory.connect(URL, USERNAME, PWD);
    influxDB.query(new Query(CREATE_DB, DB_NAME));
    influxDB.setLogLevel(InfluxDB.LogLevel.BASIC);
    influxDB.setDatabase(DB_NAME);
    return influxDB;
  }

  @Bean
  public InfluxDBAdapter influxDBAdapter(InfluxDB influxDB) {
    return new InfluxDBAdapter(influxDB);
  }
}
```

Now your `InfluxDBAdapter` needs a constructor (for dependency injection) retrieving the `InfluxDB`.

```
public class InfluxDBAdapter {
    // some private static final query Strings       

    private InfluxDB influxDB;

    InfluxDBAdapter(InfluxDB influxDB) {
      this.influxDB=influxDB;
    }

    // some more methods to utilize the database
}
```

Make sure that the `InfluXDBConfiguration` and `InfluxDBAdapter` are in the same package so that the default visible constructor can be called (default visible to prevent, easy, outside instantiation).

In the `InflxuDBConfiguration` you could remove the `static` fields containing the hardcoded username etc. and replace it with access to either the `Environment` or use an `@ConfigurationProperties` annotated class to work with [type safe properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-typesafe-configuration-properties).

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="influxdb")
@Component
public class InfluxDBProperties {

    private String url = "default-url";
    private String dbName = "default-dbname";
    private String username = "default-user";
    private String password = "default-pwd";
    // Other properties of your liking;
    // getters & setters
}
```

Now with this `InfluxDBProperties` you could add `influx.url=http://whatever` to your `application.properties` or profile specific one and have it [externally configurable](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html). You can inject it into the `influxDB` method to retrieve the properties from.

```
  @Bean
  public InfluxDB influxDB(InfluxDBProperties props) {
    InfluxDB influxDB = InfluxDBFactory.connect(props.getUrl(), props.getUsername(), props.getPassword());
    influxDB.query(new Query(CREATE_DB, props.getDbName()));
    influxDB.setLogLevel(InfluxDB.LogLevel.BASIC);
    influxDB.setDatabase(props.getDbName());
    return influxDB;
  }
```

No more statics, configurable for every environment.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much for going into this level detail! This works fantastically!

Comment: Your welcome. I just modified the question to include some links to relevant sections of the Spring Boot reference guide (for the learning experience).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this should work. Spring can invoke private constructors so there shouldn't be any issue.

But why would you want to do this? The singleton pattern goes against the basic tenant of dependency injection. If you want a singleton `InfluxDBAdapter` bean, just make it a singleton bean.

I would recommend adding a configuration class, which could look something like

```
@Configuration
public class InfluxDBConfig {
    // constants omitted...

    @Bean
    public InfluxDB influxDB() {
        final InfluxDB influxDB = InfluxDB(URL, USERNAME, PWD);
        influxDB.query(new Query(CREATE_DB, DB_NAME));
        influxDB.setLogLevel(InfluxDB.LogLevel.BASIC);
        influxDB.setDatabase(DB_NAME);
        return influxDB;
    }
}
```

You can then annotate `InfluxDBAdapter` with `@Component` since the `InfluxDB` instance can be injected. Modify the constructors of the `InfluxDB` and `InfluxDBAdapter` classes accordingly, of course.

Some of these constants can probably be provided through configuration properties so that your configuration logic isn't mangled with your business logic.

Comment: Along with annotating the class with @Component, I would need to move the logic in the getInstance method into a public constructor, correct?

Comment: @Pr0pagate I would advise against that. The point of dependency injection is to extract the logic of creating an object's dependencies outside of the class. I'll edit my answer with a better alternative.